# Return results mongoose v4 with find query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have left my code for over a year and have ran NPM install and since it obviously has changed :)

**My Query**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Clubs = mongoose.model('Clubs');

getNorsemanClubs: function(passData){
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        Clubs.find({norseman:true}, 'name teamID date norseman eleven').sort({ eleven : 'asc'})
            .then(function(clubs){
                console.info(clubs);
                passData.clubs = clubs;
                resolve(passData);
            });
    })
}
```

**console.info(clubs); Output**

[image]

Here you can see that it is returning the model rather than the results of the clubs.

**My model**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
    , Schema = mongoose.Schema;

/**
 * User Schema
 */

var ClubsScheme = new Schema({
    name: String,
    teamID: { type: String, default: null },
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now},
    norseman: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    eleven: Number
})

mongoose.model('Clubs', ClubsScheme);
```

How can I get it return a list of the clubs?

The clubs table is full of match data. But I used to get a return from `'name teamID date norseman eleven'` now I just get a return of `:\`

**Using exec()

[image]

Comment: I don't see a v5 release of Mongoose anywhere. Regardless, that warning just means that you need to add a line like `mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;` to tell Mongoose which promise library to use.

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute your `find` mongoose query method, by trailing your query with `exec()` method so that it return a **Promise** with your list values resolved, so change the following line:

```
Clubs.find({norseman:true}, 'name teamID date norseman eleven').sort({ eleven : 'asc'})
```

to:

```
Clubs.find({norseman:true}, 'name teamID date norseman eleven').sort({ eleven : 'asc'}).exec()
```

Comment: Indeed this is what I original had it as, however this has been removed in the newest version of mongoose.  This is why I'm using the now native Promise.